# Объединение трех таблиц

Tags: sql, join

Помогите пожалуйста с задачкой, вот сразу ссылка на sql fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fa636/1

Есть 3 таблицы:

```
Man:
 id, fa
Po:
 id, fa, np, sum
Gsp:
 id, fa, np
```

Нужно выбрать по `id` объединенные строки: `id`, `fa`, `np`, `sum`

При этом `id` может отсутствовать как в обеих таблицах `po` и `gsp`, так и содержаться в одной из них или в обеих. Если `id` есть в обеих таблицах `po` и `gsp` то столбец `np` брать только из `po` игнорируя `gsp`.

Что то никак не получается объединить строки из трех таблиц.
База у меня **DB2 9.7**, на `sqlfiddle.com` её нет, создал пример на **MS SQL Server 2014**

```
IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='man')
DROP DATABASE man
IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='po')
DROP DATABASE po
IF EXISTS(select * from sys.databases where name='pogsp')
DROP DATABASE pogsp

CREATE TABLE man
    ([id] varchar(3), [fa] varchar(20))
;
INSERT INTO man
    ([id], [fa])
VALUES
    ('1', 'flegontov'),
    ('3', 'terentev'),
    ('2', 'shuvalov'),
    ('4', 'chromchenko'),
    ('5', 'ivanov') 
;

CREATE TABLE po
    ([id] varchar(3), [fa] varchar(20), [np] varchar(3), [sum] varchar(3))
;
INSERT INTO po
    ([id], [fa], [np], [sum])
VALUES
    ('1', 'flegontov', 'PRE', '100'),
    ('2', 'shuvalov', 'PRE', '200'),
    ('5', 'ivanov', 'TP', '300')
;

CREATE TABLE pogsp
    ([id] varchar(3), [fa] varchar(20), [np] varchar(3))
;
INSERT INTO pogsp
    ([id], [fa], [np])
VALUES
    ('1', 'flegontov', 'NAZ'),
    ('3', 'terentev', 'SN'),
    ('2', 'shuvalov', 'PRE'),
    ('4', 'chromchenko', 'PER')
;
```

Вот так пытался сделать:

```
SELECT 
m.id, m.fa, vpl.np, vpl.sum
FROM man m

LEFT JOIN po vpl on vpl.id=m.id

left JOIN (
SELECT v.id, v.np, 'vpl.po' as baza
FROM po v
  right JOIN (
    SELECT g.id, g.np, 'vpl.pogsp' as baza
    FROM pogsp g
  ) g ON g.id = v.id
) gsp ON gsp.id = m.id

order by id
```

Вот так должно полчиться:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: приведите какой результат ожидается после выполнения запроса на приведенных тестовых данных. И может ли быть ситуация, что в какой то из таблиц какой то id встретится более 1 раза ?

Comment: *Если id есть в обеих таблицах po и gsp, то столбец np брать только из po, игнорируя gsp.* `SELECT ..., COALESCE(po.np,pogsp.np), ...`

Comment: Вот так должно получиться:     ('1', 'flegontov', 'PRE', '100'),  
    ('2', 'shuvalov', 'PRE', '200'),
    ('3', 'terentev', 'SN', ''),
    ('4', 'chromchenko', 'PER',''),
    ('5', 'ivanov', 'TP', '300')

Comment: Id не может встретиться более одного раза в таблице.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT m.id, m.fa, coalesce(vpl.np,g.np) np, vpl.sum
  FROM man m
  LEFT JOIN po vpl on vpl.id=m.id
  LEFT JOIN pogsp g on g.id = m.id
 ORDER BY id
```